# Construct symmetric binary tree plot

Tags: graphics, visualization, trees

I want to create a plot that looks like the following:
[image]

In essence, it is a symmetric plot with binary splits.
I am a Mathematica novice and don't know how to do it.

I need to be able to set the following parameters:

1. the number of split levels (in picture: 2)
2. the total width
3. the length of the vertical sections
4. the channel width (identical for vertical and horizontal sections)

I was looking `TreePlot` initially, but that seemed very complicated with my desired parameters. Then I thought it should work with `NestList` to create all the edge points (since it is a symmetric structure) and then make a `Graphics[]` object out of it. Finally I want to export the geometry to a graphics program to be able to laser cut it.

I am grateful for any help!

Answer (score 4):

This is just a starting point, not a full answer.

You can make an appropriate `Graph`, use the `"LayeredEmbedding"` or `"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"` [`GraphLayout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphLayout.html), and design a custom [`EdgeShapeFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeShapeFunction.html).

```
edge[{{x1_, y1_}, ___, {x2_, y2_}}, _] := 
 Line[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y1}, {x2, y2}}]

KaryTree[7, EdgeShapeFunction -> edge]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This will generalize well because you can use it with in an arbitrary graph. You can set the [`EdgeStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeStyle.html), get rid of vertices, etc. to control the result better.

The following is just an example to show what parameters you can control. You will probably not want to use all of these.  Be sure to look up the suboptions of the various relevant graph layouts.

```
KaryTree[10, 3, 
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> 4, 
   "Orientation" -> Bottom, "LeafDistance" -> 3, 
   LayerSizeFunction -> (2 &)},
 EdgeShapeFunction -> edge, 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], AbsoluteThickness[5], Gray], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> None]
```

---

There is also the slightly different `IGLayoutReingoldTilford` layout functions from [the IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM). You may be able to get more control over the precise sizing.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I am currently trying to adapt your ideas to my needs. I think I am already quite far, but one thing I don't understand (there is very little documentation on it) is "LeafDistance". What exactly does it do? What units does it have (printer points, pixel, ...)?

Comment: @Niki I do not know. I put in frames to see the exact size, but the units do not make sense to me. If you get frustrated with this, you can try my IGraph/M package, as I suggested above.  Example: `IGLayoutReingoldTilford[
 Uncompress@Compress@KaryTree[10, 3],
 "RootVertices" -> {4},
 EdgeShapeFunction -> edge, "Rotation" -> Pi,
 "LayerHeight" -> 1, "LeafDistance" -> 1,
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], AbsoluteThickness[5], Gray], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> None, FrameTicks -> Automatic, Frame -> True]`. The Compress/Uncompress thing is to work around a Mathematica bug ...

Comment: @Niki The units are plain plot units with the IGraph/M layout functions.

Answer (score 4):

In versions 10.4+, `Dendrogram` produces desired shapes when input a `Graph` with `VertexWeights`.

In the following, we add vertex `0` to `CompleteKaryTree` with `n` levels and obtain the required `VertexWeights` based on the layer a node occupies. The resulting vertex-weighted graph is used as input to `Dendrogram`. The function `dendrogramF` below constructs the appropriate graph to pass to `Dendrogram` and postprocesses the output to produce the desired results.

The first argument of the function `dendrogramF` (`nk = {n, k}`) controls the number of layers (`n`) and, optionally, the arity (`k`). A singleton list `{n}` for the argument gives binary tree with `n` levels. The second argument (`length`) of the function modifies the vertex weights to give the desired length for the vertical sections. The third argument (`w`) controls the `AbsoluteThickness` of the lines to give the desired *channel widths*. We don't have an argument to control  *Total width* directly; desired horizontal width can be obtained playing with the settings of the `ImageSize` option.

```
dendrogramF[color_ : Black, o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{nk = #, length = #2, w = #3, ckat, ckat2, edges, vertices, vertexweights},
    ckat = CompleteKaryTree[##& @@ nk, DirectedEdges -> True];
    edges = Sort[Sort /@ EdgeList[ckat2 = EdgeAdd[ckat, 0 -> 1]]];
    vertices = Sort@VertexList[ckat2];
    vertexweights = length (Reverse[ArrayComponents[Reverse[Length /@ 
      (VertexOutComponent[ckat2, #] & /@ vertices)]]] - 1);
    Show[Dendrogram[Graph[edges, VertexWeight -> vertexweights], Bottom] /.
     l : Line[__] :> {color, AbsoluteThickness[w], (l /. {{a_, b_}, {a_, b_}} :> Nothing)},
     o, AspectRatio -> 1/2]] &;
```

Examples:

```
dendrogramF[][{3}, 1, 20]
```

[image]

```
dendrogramF[][{4}, 1, 15]
```

[image]

```
dendrogramF[Black, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 600][{4, 3}, 1, 10]
```

[image]

```
dendrogramF[Black, AspectRatio -> 1/4, ImageSize -> 700][{5, 3}, 1, 5]
```

[image]

```
dendrogramF[Blue, AspectRatio -> 1/4, ImageSize -> 500][{3, 6}, 1, 5]
```

[image]

```
dendrogramF[Blue, AspectRatio -> 1/4, ImageSize -> 700][{6, 3}, 1, 1]
```

[image]

```
dendrogramF[Red, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 400, 
    PlotRangePadding -> {{10, 10}, {1, 1}}][{5}, 1, 10]
```

[image]

```
dendrogramF[Red, Frame->True, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 400,
    PlotRangePadding->{{10, 10},{5, 5}}][{5}, 10, 10]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Thickness[channelwidth], 

   Line[{{0, 0}, {0, level1}}],
   Line[{{-totalwidth/4, level1}, {totalwidth/4, level1}}],

   Line[{{-3 totalwidth/8, level2}, {-totalwidth/8, level2}}],
   Line[{{totalwidth/8, level2}, {3 totalwidth/8, level2}}],

   Line[{{-totalwidth/4, level1}, {-totalwidth/4, level2}}],
   Line[{{totalwidth/4, level1}, {totalwidth/4, level2}}],

   Line[{{-3 totalwidth/8, level2}, {-3 totalwidth/8, 1}}],
   Line[{{-totalwidth/8, level2}, {-totalwidth/8, 1}}],

   Line[{{totalwidth/8, level2}, {totalwidth/8, 1}}],
   Line[{{3 totalwidth/8, level2}, {3 totalwidth/8, 1}}]

   },
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 1}}],
 {totalwidth, 1, 2},
 {level1, .1, .3},
 {level2, .4, .8},
 {channelwidth, .01, .03}
 ]
```

[image]

The lines could be generated algorithmically rather than explicitly listed, of course.

Comment: Thanks, but I was rather looking for a method to generate the points/lines and also be able to generalize the method to any number of levels.