# Create a simple split tree

Tags: graphics, fractals

I am trying to create a simple split tree.

[image: split tree]

The growth should be only upwards, the vertical element length constant (1), the size of the horizontal bars should be halved in each iteration and the number of split levels should be freely chosen.

I found a very similar question [Using Mathematica to create an H-Tree](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146797), but I cannot adopt the answers to solve my problem.
I guess `NestList` is doing the job, but I didn't get further than:

```
drawT[{x_, y_}, size_] :=
 Line[{{{x + size, y}, {x - size, y}}, {{x + size, 
     y + size}, {x + size, y}}, {{x - size, y + size}, {x - size, 
     y}}}]
```

I basically don't know how to use the above function `drawT`, that creates the U-shaped geometry to be iterated in `NestList`.

Grateful for any help.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143154/7339

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I like recursion so I've written a recursive solution.

Helper function for doing the drawing the basic u-shaped element of the tree

```
draw[x0_, x1_, y0_, y1_] := Line[{{x0, y1}, {x0, y0}, {x1, y0}, {x1, y1}}]
```

Helper function for doing the recursion

```
treeF[lvls_, lvl_, xy_, w_, h_] :=
  Module[{x0, x1, y0, y1},
    {x0, x1} = xy[[1]] + w {-1, 1}/2;
    {y0, y1} = xy[[2]] + {0, h};
    tree = {tree, draw[x0, x1, y0, y1]};
    If[lvl < lvls,
      treeF[lvls, lvl + 1, {x0, y1}, w/2, h];
      treeF[lvls, lvl + 1, {x1, y1}, w/2, h]]]
```

The main function

```
splitTree[levels_Integer?Positive, minW_: 1, ht_: 1] :=
  Block[{tree = {}},
    treeF[levels, 1, {0, 0}, baseW = 2^(levels - 1) minW, ht];
    Graphics[tree]]
```

Examples of use

```
splitTree[5]
```

[image: tree5]

```
Show[splitTree[7, 1, 5], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: tree7.1.5]

Answer (score 13):

One idea is to use [`Dendrogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dendrogram) on a [`KaryTree`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KaryTree). Here is a function that does this:

```
splitTree[n_Integer?Positive] := Dendrogram @ KaryTree[
    2^(n+1) - 1,
    VertexWeight -> Floor @ Log2[Range[2^(n+1) - 1]]
]
```

An example:

```
splitTree[4]
```

[image]

One can use [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) options to control the size. For example:

```
Show[splitTree[6], ImageSize->{300, 30}, AspectRatio->Full]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I still accepted the other one, because I always find custom modifying KaryTrees in Mathematica is a pain.

Answer (score 2):

Repeated scaling + translation is another possibility:

```
With[{n = 7},
     Graphics[Flatten[NestList[(# /. Line[l_] :> 
                                With[{c = -Mean[l[[{2, -2}]]]}, 
                                     Line /@ Outer[TranslationTransform[#2][#1] &,
                                                   l[[{-1, 1}]], 
                                                   TranslationTransform[c][l].
                                                   DiagonalMatrix[{1/2, 1}], 1]]) &,
                               {Line[{{-16, 1}, {-16, 0}, {16, 0}, {16, 1}}]}, n]]]]
```

[image: tree]

Answer (score 2):

Iterative version

```
n = 6;
s = 8;
m = {{{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}, {#, 1}} & /@ {-s, s};
L = Line[{{-s, 1}, {-s, 0}, {s, 0}, {s, 1}}];
Graphics[NestList[GeometricTransformation[#, m] &, L, n]]
```

[image]

Comment: You don't have to map `TranslationTransform[]`: `TranslationTransform[{0, h}][With[{d = (A - B)/4}, {{A - d, A + d}, {B - d, B + d}}]]`